# Pandas: create multiple rows in a df for an exploded column containing list values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe such that

```
        A       B        C  
0       14      218     [{u'END_DT': None, u'ARBITRARY_ID':...   
1       19      263     [{u'END_DT': None, u'ARBITRARY_ID':...
```

Column C is a list of dictionary. I wanted to explode the list so that for each index there are multiple rows for the number of dictionaries(elements in the list). There are multiple ways of doing so but I am stuck at one particular stage and curious about solving it. I have exploded the column C like this:

```
df.C.apply(pd.Series).stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True).to_frame('C')
```

So what I get back is :

```
                C
0   {u'END_DT': None, u'ARBITRARY_ID': ...
0   {u'END_DT': None, u'ARBITRARY_ID': ...
0   {u'END_DT': None, u'ARBITRARY_ID': ...
0   {u'END_DT': None, u'ARBITRARY_ID': ...
0   {u'END_DT': None, u'ARBITRARY_ID': ...
1   {u'END_DT': None, u'ARBITRARY_ID': ...
1   {u'END_DT': 1475149637313, u'ARBITRARY_ID...
1   {u'END_DT': None, u'ARBITRARY_ID': ...
1   {u'END_DT': 1475149637313, u'ARBITRARY_ID...
2   {u'END_DT': None, u'ARBITRARY_ID': ...
2   {u'END_DT': None, u'ARBITRARY_ID': ...
```

Is there any way to join this to my main df seeing that the indexes match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First remove original column `C` by [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html), then [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) and last [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for unique `index`:

```
a = df.C.apply(pd.Series).stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True).to_frame('C')
df = df.drop('C', axis=1).join(a).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Faster alternative for `a` Series:

```
a = pd.DataFrame(df.C.values.tolist()).stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True).to_frame('C')
```